# OutOfMemoryError with DFS

Tags: java, optimization, refactoring

So I'm in quite of a pickle. When I first created my DFS Algorithm I used recursion. This resulted in getting a StackOverflow error. Well... No big deal I'll just convert it to iteration. So I converted my code to iteration, and I used a Stack to replicate method calls. However, now I'm getting OutOfMemoryError.

I actually just found out my problem, there was a circular dependency. (Stupid me) However, I'm curious how someone else would have approached this if there wasn't a circular dependency. I should also mention this was in Java.

My question is pretty much what to do when you know you don't have an infinite loop, but encounter an OutOfMemoryError because of a Stack from a DFS search.

Comment: Could you describe the type of problem you are trying to search/solve? To me it seems that DFS is just not appropriate for the type of problem you are trying to solve. The solution might be on a branch that you never reach due to DFS getting stuck in one of the unpromising branches. But even this is unlikely, probably you are just allocating and holding onto too much memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common cause of stack overflow and out of memory errors is that the program uses an algorithm that requires O(n) storage (or more), and the best course of action is to find an algorithm or trick to use less storage, like O(1) or O(log n). The most common example is processing a big files in constant-sized blocks, i.e. with O(1) storage, rather than reading it entirely into memory first, which is O(n).

Another common cause of these errors are simple mistakes: accumulating garbage that you don't need anymore or creating new objects when the algorithm requires reusing ones that exist. Also in this case the appropriate solution is locating the bug and fixing it.

Only when you are sure the algorithm is as memory conservative as you can reasonably make it and that there are no memory bugs it makes sense to play with the JVM memory parameters (`-Xss` to set the stack size, `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to set the initial and maximum heap sizes).

Answer (score 1):

A stackOverflow means exactly what it says, since you had a recursive algorithm, this means that your memory stack (for function calls) has overflown. take a look at the call stack document to understand how stack pointers, frames, and return pointers work: [Call Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

When you created an itereative algorithm, you run out of memory because the variables you are storing are not on the Call Stack but are stored in the memory of the function itself (within the same stack frame).

Of course, technically both errors mean you have no memory left, but each of them happened in a different way. One is by non-ending recursive calls to a method and another by overflowing the memory.

**EDIT**
With regards to your edited question, I don't think a stackOverflow can happen with no infinite loop or recursion unless you do not have enough memory in your system. Maybe add more RAM?

Comment: Thanks let me fix my question. Right I removed the recursive part because it didn't fit in with my question. (It was part of my original question)

Answer (score 1):

In pretty much all cases, if you hit a memory related exception the first thing to do is have a long and hard think about what you're doing (possibly assisted by a memory profiler).  There is a very good chance you're holding on to data you don't need anymore.

That being said, if you're sure your program is behaving in an efficient manner and your problems are simply due to the size and/or complexity of your data set, you can increase the stack or heap used by your application:

```
-Xss64m
```

Sets stack size to 64 meg

```
-Xmx1024m
```

Sets heap size to 1 gig.